# CSS: box-shadow width with percentage

Tags: html, css

Im building our tool followinf the provided design, and we are trying to draw a line on the table row (using box-shadow) but we need it on a specific width (not all over the row, lets say 30% of the row and not all of it).

We tried using "width" but nothing really works.

here is the jsfiddle we made for the example:
https://jsfiddle.net/7va8t56z/4/

here is how we draw the line:

```
tbody tr { 
    box-shadow: inset 1px 2px 1px 0px rgb(82, 243, 109);
}
```

can you reduce the green line width without changing the table\row length? (only the box-shadow width)

here is an example of how it should look like:
[image: example]

Thank you.

Comment: Can _you_ go stand outside in the sun, and throw only "half" a shadow ...? No, of course not - that's not how a shadow works. You'll need something other than a box-shadow here. Either apply a border to specific table cells only; or maybe use an absolutely positioned pseudo element.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks, but, I use shadow because I need a full shadow for the table line, I'm using a circle shape for it, and I'm using an inset to place it in the right place, this is why its the perfect solution, the width is my only limitation (I tried using "border" but it never fit into the exact shape of the row).

Comment: Have you corrected the reported linting error, of the unmatched `</th>`; in the JS Fiddle HTML pane click on the "tidy" (appears on hovering the relevant panel), and then scroll down to see - and then hover over - the red dot in the left gutter. Also, could you add some form of image showing where you want the (approximately) 30% line/shadow to be, on the table?

Comment: @DavidThomas Thanks, I just fixed it see here: https://jsfiddle.net/u1m74ecz/

and the 30% is just an estimation, But I'll add the image into the question, Thank you

Comment: So you want to highlight the first portion of the `<tbody>`, or every row? With just the initial corner segment, or did you want something more aesthetic, or complex?

Comment: I have many great answers, Thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may prefer to apply this style only to the first 2 columns

```
table { 
  border-spacing: 0;
}

tbody tr td:nth-child(1) {
  box-shadow: inset 1px 2px 0px 0px rgb(82, 243, 109);
}

tbody tr td:nth-child(2) {
  box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 0px 0px rgb(82, 243, 109);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, its working great! I think I will use this solution.

Answer (score 1):

If the `box-shadow` is the only option for you then you could use multiple shadows.

```
tbody tr { 
  box-shadow: 
   /* apply the same color as your background color for the first shadow
   and adjust the first value as needed */
   inset -50vw -10px 0 10px #161d31,
   inset -5px 1px 0 2px rgb(82, 243, 109)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest the following approach, with explanatory comments in the CSS and JavaScript (the JavaScript is largely redundant, and only exists so you can see the highlighted and non-highlighted states):

```js
// here we retrieve the first/only <button> element, and then use EventTarget.addEventListener()
// to bind the anonymous arrow function as the event-handler for the 'click' event:
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click',
  // within the function body we find the <tbody> element within the document, and
  // use the Element.classList API to toggle the 'showHighlight' class on that
  // <tbody> element:
  () => document.querySelector('tbody').classList.toggle('showHighlight')
);
```

```css
body.dark-layout {
  background-color: #161d31;
  color: #fff;
}

/* it seems that you want to position the "highlighting" in relation
   to the size of the <tr>, rather than the <td> elements; therefore
   we add position: relative to that <tr> in order that the pseudo-
   element is positioned in relation to the <tr>: */
tbody tr {
  position: relative;
}

/* here we use the "showHighlight" class-name as part of the selector
   in order to only show the highlight when the class is present; this
   is purely to show the difference and should almost certainly be
   removed in production (according to your preferences); otherwise we
   simply style the ::before pseudo-element of the first <td> element
   of each <tr> within the <tbody>: */
tbody.showHighlight tr td:first-child::before {
  /* the borders of the element: */
  border: 2px solid hsl(120deg 60% 50% / 1);
  /* making the unwanted borders transparent, to give the desired
     half-shadow look: */
  border-block-end-color: transparent;
  border-inline-end-color: transparent;
  /* to ensure that the pseudo-element is shown at all: */
  content: '';
  /* setting the block-size (a CSS logical property, referring to the
     element's size on the block-axis; equivalent to 'height' in
     languages that run either left-to-right, or right-to-left and then
     top-to-bottom, such as most Latin and European languages): */
  block-size: 100%;
  /* setting the size of the element - in relation to the <tr> - on the
     inline-axis (another CSS logical property, equivalent to 'width'
     in left-to-right, and right-to-left languages such as English and
     most European languages); here it's set to 30% but, of course, can
     be adjusted to your preference: */
  inline-size: 30%;
  /* to prevent pointer-events (:hover, clicks, selection) being prevented
     by the pseudo-element lying on top of the <td> element below: */
     pointer-events: none;
  /* taking the element out of the flow of the document: */
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<body class="dark-layout">
  <!-- added this button to allow a comparison of the table with, and without, the highlight applied: -->
  <button id="toggleHighlight">Toggle highlight</button>
  <table style="width: 100%;">
    <thead role="rowgroup">
      <tr role="row">
        <th role="columnheader" scope="col" aria-colindex="1" class="" style="width: 20%">
        <th style="width: 20%;"></th>
        <th role="columnheader" scope="col" aria-colindex="4" class="" style="width: 50px;">
          <div class="text-nowrap cursor-pointer text-center">
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center text-capitalize"><span> 7D % </span> <span class="my-auto d-inline"></span></div>
          </div>
        </th>
        <th role="columnheader" scope="col" aria-colindex="5" class="" style="width: 50px;">
          <div class="text-nowrap cursor-pointer text-center">
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center text-capitalize"><span> MC </span> <span class="my-auto d-inline"></span></div>
          </div>
        </th>
        <th role="columnheader" scope="col" aria-colindex="6" class="" style="width: 50px;">
          <div class="text-nowrap cursor-pointer text-center">
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center text-capitalize"><span> VOL(24h) </span> </div>
          </div>
        </th>
        <th role="columnheader" scope="col" aria-colindex="7" class="" style="width: 50px;">
          <div class="text-nowrap cursor-pointer text-center">
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center text-capitalize"><span> ROI in X's </span> <span class="my-auto d-inline"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="8px" height="8px" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-triangle" style="rotate: 180deg; margin-left: 5px; margin-top: -9px;">
                  <path d="M10.29 3.86L1.82 18a2 2 0 0 0 1.71 3h16.94a2 2 0 0 0 1.71-3L13.71 3.86a2 2 0 0 0-3.42 0z"></path>
                </svg></span></div>
          </div>
        </th>
        <th role="columnheader" scope="col" aria-colindex="8" class="" style="width: 50px;">
          <div class="text-nowrap cursor-pointer text-center">
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center text-capitalize"><span> ROI % </span> <span class="my-auto d-inline"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="8px" height="8px" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-triangle" style="rotate: 180deg; margin-left: 5px; margin-top: -9px;">
                  <path d="M10.29 3.86L1.82 18a2 2 0 0 0 1.71 3h16.94a2 2 0 0 0 1.71-3L13.71 3.86a2 2 0 0 0-3.42 0z"></path>
                </svg></span></div>
          </div>
        </th>
        <th role="columnheader" scope="col" aria-colindex="9" class="" style="width: 50px;">
          <div class="text-nowrap cursor-pointer text-center">
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center text-capitalize"><span> Total Supply % </span> <span class="my-auto d-inline"></span></div>
          </div>
        </th>
        <th role="columnheader" scope="col" aria-colindex="10" class="" style="width: 50px;">
          <div class="text-nowrap cursor-pointer text-center">
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center text-capitalize"><span> Circulating Supply </span> <span class="my-auto d-inline"></span></div>
          </div>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody role="rowgroup">
      <!---->
      <tr role="row">
        <td>
          1
          <b>Bitcoin</b><br>
          <div class="text-nowrap text-truncate text-left" style="float: left; max-width: 100px; width: 100px; opacity: 0.8;">
            BTC
          </div>
        </td>
        <td aria-colindex="2" role="cell" class="">
          <div class="text-center m-auto greenFlash" style="width: 100px;">
            $16,823.86</div>
        </td>
        <td aria-colindex="3" role="cell" class="">
          <div><span class="text-success-green">0.1
              <span> %</span></span></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</body>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/egwp5szj/).

An adaptation of the above, to allow for some experimentation:

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click',

  () => document.querySelector('tbody').classList.toggle('showHighlight')
);

document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('input', (evt) => {
  let tbody = document.querySelector('tbody'),
    color = document.querySelector('input[type=color]'),
    inlineSize = document.querySelector('input[type=range]');
  [color, inlineSize].forEach(
    (el) => {
      let output = el.closest('label').querySelector('output');
      tbody.style.setProperty(`--${el.name}`, isNaN(el.value) ? el.value : `${el.value}%`);
      if (output) {
        output.textContent = el.value;
      }
    });
});
```

```css
*,
::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body.dark-layout {
  background-color: #161d31;
  color: #fff;
}

tbody tr {
  position: relative;
}

tbody.showHighlight tr td:first-child::before {
  border: 2px solid var(--color, hsl(120deg 60% 50% / 1));
  border-block-end-color: transparent;
  border-inline-end-color: transparent;
  content: '';
  block-size: 100%;
  inline-size: var(--inlineSize, 30%);
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
}

form {
  display: grid;
  gap: 0.5em;
  inline-size: clamp(30em, 70%, 1200px);
  margin-block: 1em;
  margin-inline: auto;
}

fieldset {
  display: grid;
  gap: inherit;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(45%, 1fr));
}

label {
  align-content: stretch;
  display: flex;
  gap: inherit;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

label>* {
  display: flex;
  margin-block: auto;
}

output {
  flex-basis: 4em;
  background-color: hsl(150deg 90% 90% / 0.9);
}

output::after {
  content: '%';
}

output:empty::after {
  content: '';
}

@media screen and (width <=880px) {
  label {
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: start;
  }
  label>* {
    justify-content: center;
    inline-size: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    margin-block: 0;
  }
  label>input {
    flex-grow: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<body class="dark-layout">
  <form action="#">
    <fieldset>
      <label>
        <span class="labelText">Select highlight color:</span>
        <input name="color" type="color" value="#32CD32">
      </label>
      <label>
        <span class="labelText">Select width of highlight (%):</span>
        <input name="inlineSize" type="range" min="1" max="100" step="0.5" value="30">
        <output></output>
        </label>
    </fieldset>
    <button type="button" id="toggleHighlight">Toggle highlight</button>
  </form>
  <table style="width: 100%;">
    <thead role="rowgroup">
      <tr role="row">
        <th role="columnheader" scope="col" aria-colindex="1" class="" style="width: 20%">
          <th style="width: 20%;"></th>
          <th role="columnheader" scope="col" aria-colindex="4" class="" style="width: 50px;">
            <div class="text-nowrap cursor-pointer text-center">
              <div class="d-flex justify-content-center text-capitalize"><span> 7D % </span> <span class="my-auto d-inline"></span></div>
            </div>
          </th>
          <th role="columnheader" scope="col" aria-colindex="5" class="" style="width: 50px;">
            <div class="text-nowrap cursor-pointer text-center">
              <div class="d-flex justify-content-center text-capitalize"><span> MC </span> <span class="my-auto d-inline"></span></div>
            </div>
          </th>
          <th role="columnheader" scope="col" aria-colindex="6" class="" style="width: 50px;">
            <div class="text-nowrap cursor-pointer text-center">
              <div class="d-flex justify-content-center text-capitalize"><span> VOL(24h) </span> </div>
            </div>
          </th>
          <th role="columnheader" scope="col" aria-colindex="7" class="" style="width: 50px;">
            <div class="text-nowrap cursor-pointer text-center">
              <div class="d-flex justify-content-center text-capitalize"><span> ROI in X's </span> <span class="my-auto d-inline"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="8px" height="8px" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-triangle" style="rotate: 180deg; margin-left: 5px; margin-top: -9px;">
                  <path d="M10.29 3.86L1.82 18a2 2 0 0 0 1.71 3h16.94a2 2 0 0 0 1.71-3L13.71 3.86a2 2 0 0 0-3.42 0z"></path>
                </svg></span></div>
            </div>
          </th>
          <th role="columnheader" scope="col" aria-colindex="8" class="" style="width: 50px;">
            <div class="text-nowrap cursor-pointer text-center">
              <div class="d-flex justify-content-center text-capitalize"><span> ROI % </span> <span class="my-auto d-inline"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="8px" height="8px" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-triangle" style="rotate: 180deg; margin-left: 5px; margin-top: -9px;">
                  <path d="M10.29 3.86L1.82 18a2 2 0 0 0 1.71 3h16.94a2 2 0 0 0 1.71-3L13.71 3.86a2 2 0 0 0-3.42 0z"></path>
                </svg></span></div>
            </div>
          </th>
          <th role="columnheader" scope="col" aria-colindex="9" class="" style="width: 50px;">
            <div class="text-nowrap cursor-pointer text-center">
              <div class="d-flex justify-content-center text-capitalize"><span> Total Supply % </span> <span class="my-auto d-inline"></span></div>
            </div>
          </th>
          <th role="columnheader" scope="col" aria-colindex="10" class="" style="width: 50px;">
            <div class="text-nowrap cursor-pointer text-center">
              <div class="d-flex justify-content-center text-capitalize"><span> Circulating Supply </span> <span class="my-auto d-inline"></span></div>
            </div>
          </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody role="rowgroup">
      <!---->
      <tr role="row">
        <td>
          1
          <b>Bitcoin</b><br>
          <div class="text-nowrap text-truncate text-left" style="float: left; max-width: 100px; width: 100px; opacity: 0.8;">
            BTC
          </div>
        </td>
        <td aria-colindex="2" role="cell" class="">
          <div class="text-center m-auto greenFlash" style="width: 100px;">
            $16,823.86</div>
        </td>
        <td aria-colindex="3" role="cell" class="">
          <div><span class="text-success-green">0.1
              <span> %</span></span>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</body>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/egwp5szj/1/).

References:

- CSS:

  - [`background-color`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-color).
  - [`::before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before).
  - [`border`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border).
  - [`color`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color).
  - [`content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content).
  - [CSS logical properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Logical_Properties).
  - [CSS pseudo-elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements).
  - [`block-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/block-size).
  - [`hsl()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/hsl).
  - [`inline-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inline-size).
  - [`position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position).
- JavaScript:

  - [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
  - [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
  - [`Element.classList` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).
  - [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

Comment: Wow! nice one, Ill check it

Comment: Hopefully it'll be of use.